# php rename() is moving two folders instead of one

Tags: php, rename, move

in folder 'original' i have subfolders called 1, 2, 11, 33, 111... they are all numbers

this script sorts array then moves first folder (in this case folder 1) to the folder 'move-here'

everything works ok, BUT it moves 2 folders each time instead of just one, folders 1 & 11 are moved in my first try

echo is giving me 'moved folder: 1', so i really don't know why rename() is moving 2 folders?

```
$wallpapers = array_map('basename',glob("/path-to-folder/original/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR));
natsort($wallpapers);
$wallpaper = $wallpapers[0];
if (empty($wallpaper)) {
    echo "0 folders in that directory";
    die();
}
if (!file_exists("/path-to-folder/original/$wallpaper")) {
    echo "folder does not exist";
    die();
}
echo "moved folder: $wallpaper";
rename("/path-to-folder/original/$wallpaper/","/path-to-folder/move-here/$wallpaper/");
```

Comment: Are you kidding is it just the first try ore it always move the two folders!???
"you said folders 1 & 11 are moved in my first try". you run the script two that's all.

Comment: each time it moves 2 with 1 run

Comment: I tested your code on my machine and everything works just fine. Are you sure it is moving two folders? Have you deleted all the folders in `move-here`?

Comment: i'm positive, i'm checking it via ftp, and after just one run it deletes 2 folders in original, and they are transfered to move-here folder. folders 1 & 11

Comment: oh boy, oh boy, i found where the problem is, stupid htaccess redirect (www to non-www) loads page 2 times, that's why it's moving 2 folders

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the similar issue , but  i have fixed it using the integer conversion function `intval()` . php sorting also have similar issue in some cases.

```
rename("/path-to-folder/original/$wallpaper/","/path-to-folder/move-here/$wallpaper/");
```

to

```
rename("/path-to-folder/original/".intval($wallpaper)."/","/path-to-folder/move-here/".intval($wallpaper)."/");
```

Comment: it's still moving 2 folders each time hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine i just tested it and it only moves one folder.
Check if your script is not excuted two times.

```
<?php
$wallpapers = array_map('basename',glob("./folder1/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR));
natsort($wallpapers);
$wallpaper = $wallpapers[0];
if (empty($wallpaper)) {
    echo "0 folders in that directory";
    die();
}
if (!file_exists("./folder1/$wallpaper")) {
    echo "folder does not exist";
    die();
}
echo "moved folder: $wallpaper";
rename("./folder1/$wallpaper/","./folder2/$wallpaper/");


$data = scandir("./folder2/");
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
```

Result of scan dir:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => .
        [1] => ..
        [2] => 1
    )
```

Comment: yep, that's the problem :)

Comment: Maybe you can use var_dump(debug_backtrace()); to see where this code is called